# ConvertToAbsoluteDirection() in ItemTouchHelper.callback

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, itemtouchhelper

I'm trying to create a Recycler view with a swipe feature to Add to favorites.

I've read about the ItemTouchHelper class and how to keep the cards from totally sliding over. I couldn't understand the function below

```
public int convertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection)
{
            if (swipeBack)
            {
                  swipeBack = false;
                  return 0;
            }
            return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags,layoutDirection);
}
```

Can someone explain the significance of the return value and the super.convertToAbsoluteDirection call?

Answer (score 0):

In `ItemTouchHelper#select` method, which will be called by touch/fling process, `convertToAbsoluteDirection` is called by `swipeIfNecessary`:

```
   void select(@Nullable ViewHolder selected, int actionState) {
    ...
    if (mSelected != null) {
        ...
        if (prevSelected.itemView.getParent() != null) {
            // convertToAbsoluteDirection called here in swipeIfNecessary 
            final int swipeDir = prevActionState == ACTION_STATE_DRAG ? 0 : swipeIfNecessary(prevSelected);
            releaseVelocityTracker();
            // find where we should animate to
            final float targetTranslateX, targetTranslateY;
            int animationType;
            switch (swipeDir) {
                ...
                // if convertToAbsoluteDirection returns 0, code will go here
                default:
                    targetTranslateX = 0;
                    targetTranslateY = 0;
            }
            // targetTranslateX and targetTranslateY are 0, recover item view to default place
            final RecoverAnimation rv = new RecoverAnimation(prevSelected, animationType,
                    prevActionState, currentTranslateX, currentTranslateY,
                    targetTranslateX, targetTranslateY)
            ...
     }
}
```

That's all I learned from taking breakpoint at `convertToAbsoluteDirection`.